# How to check drupal user role in module written by Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, drupal, drupal-modules

I have written a web application using Zend framework, and I convertered it to the drupal module using ".module" file.

But I need to authorize current drupal user in that module.

How could I check the drupal user role in Zend?

By the way I find out Drupal has its own session handler to store data in database and zend use default handler which store sessions data into file system.
So it make them separate.

Any solution?

Comment: What you mean by "Drupal module written by Zend Framework" ?

Comment: @AyeshK I have written a web app using Zend Framework and converted it to a drupal module using ".module" file.

Answer (score 2):

It's considered bad practice to check the roles array itself in Drupal, the correct method is to assign an appropriate permission to that role, and check for that permission with [`user_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7), e.g.

```
if (user_access('an appropriate permission')) {
  // User is authorised.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you actually have a Drupal module.

Try

```
<?php
global $user;
if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {

}
```

Comment: I don't have access to $user variable, because the module is completely separate from drupal and its bootstrap. :|

Comment: You need to update your question then because you're really not explaining your problem very well at all.

Comment: @mousavian See http://www.interworks.com/blogs/jkhalaj/2012/05/01/how-bootstrap-drupal